# UI Design with Elements having rounded corners

Tags: user-interface, maui

how could I realize a UI Design in .NET MAUI similar to the UI on the following picture?

I am looking for something similar having a larger picture on top and a white area below with rounded corners, maybe a bit smaller in width so that the picture from the top can fade out.

Currently, I can’t get rid of my top Title View (the small bar with the title on top of my Content page). Also my white area below that is rectangular.

Is there a possibility to fade out a picture from so that the white are from a ContentPage is on top of that visually?

[image]

**What I mean by FadeOut is a blurred effect like on this photo, not an animation!**

[image]

Comment: most visual elements support a `CornerRadius` property

Comment: And for fading animations you can use : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/basic?view=net-maui-7.0 FadeTo (which also work on most visual elements)

Comment: The screenshot do not have a Titlebar or TitleView, is there a way to remove this and replace with the image? Or is this just a simple ContentPage with an image in the layout which is then fade? On top of that another visual element with rounded corners, somehow on top of other elements and has to be done in code instead of XAML?

Comment: What platforms do you intend to run this on?

Comment: I intend to use it on iOS (including iPhone and iPad) and Android Mobile phones. No Windows Plattforms

Comment: By the way, I maybe used the wrong word as translation - FadeOut wasn’t meant to be an effect for an animation, it should be more transparent to the bottom as can be seen on the second image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Frame` to make the Elements having rounded corners. In addition, the `LinearGradientBrush` can help you to make the fadeout effect.

Here is the demo I made by using the `Frame` and `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp24.MainPage"
             BackgroundImageSource="splash_logo.png">

    <ScrollView>

        <ScrollView.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                          Offset="0.4" />
                <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="0.6" />
                <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="0.8" />
                <GradientStop Color="White"
                          Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ScrollView.Background>

        <Frame CornerRadius="15" Padding="10"  HeightRequest="400" WidthRequest="350">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="15"
      
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="100"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

More information about the L[inearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/lineargradient?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-vertical-linear-gradient) and [Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame?view=net-maui-7.0).

Here is the sample effect:

[image]